# kendo datepicker Component current date is not displaying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working on MVC with kendo controls but instead of current date default date is displaying

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Format("{0: dd/MM/yyyy}")
                     .Name("datepicker")
                     .Min(DateTime.Today)
                     .Value(Model.LaunchDate)
                     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" , @id = "datepicker" }))
```

Comment: have you set the correct culture for your date format. the default date format for kendo controls is en-US

Comment: No I have not set the current culture for my Date format

Comment: If you take out your format option does the `launchdate` value get loaded in correctly? If it does then you will have to either set the kendo controls to use an appropriate culture this link should help https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/overview please there a number of other questions on here that have dealt with setting the culture either at control or site level.

Comment: Solved it!Thank you Very Much !

Comment: it maybe worth just adding your solution to the question to help others on the site should they come across this question.

Comment: Actually Below c# code solved my problem. `viewModel.LaunchDate = Convert.ToDateTime(viewModel.LaunchDate.HasValue ? viewModel.LaunchDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());`